# Why parallelize, when one thread have to wait for another?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

In pthread is functions to make thread wait for result from previous thread. But why? It is worse than serial. You use only one thread at time, and waste power to create and manage threads.

Are there situations when it is useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that if *all* your threads do is always just wait for every other thread to not be doing anything, that's pointless and you should redesign your program.

But I've not ever encountered an application of multi-threading that does this. Typically threads have the opportunity to run in parallel, only *occasionally* synchronising when data needs to be passed between them. Sure, thread B might need to wait for thread A to finish its work, but thread B can still get on with its own work in parallel first.

This flexibility is the power of multi-threading, and threads are arguably not of much use if you *never* pass data between them.

You have to decide whether multi-threading is right for your application, based on what it does.